# KarmaJS, Jasmine, RequireJS, etc: How to Use Require for Testing Modules

Tags: unit-testing, requirejs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

## Running Karma + Jasmine Tests with RequireJS -- Getting off the ground

#### Help! . . . _ _ _ . . . SOS!

Currently, I have an exercise project up for getting comfortable with KarmaJS -- and Unit Testing, at large. The broad issue is that I really have no transparent view of what Karma is doing behind the scenes, and I can't seem to find adequate documentation in relevant areas. Without further delay...

Here is my **folder structure**:

```
root
    |-/lib
        |-/[dependencies] (/angular, /angular-mocks, /bootstrap, /etc)  # from bower
    |-/src                                                              
        |-/[unreferenced directories] (/js, /css, /views)               # not referenced anywhere
        |-app.js                                                        # sets up angular.module('app', ...)
        |-globals.js                                                    # may be referenced in RequireJS main file; not used.
        |-index.html                                                    # loads bootstrap.css and RequireJS main file
        |-main.js                                                       # .config + require(['app', 'etc'])
        |-routeMap.js                                                   # sets up a single route
        |-test-file.js                                                  # *** simple define(function(){ return {...}; })
    |-/test
        |-/spec
            |-test-test-file.js                                         # *** require || define(['test-file'])
    |-.bowerrc                                                          # { "directory": "lib" }
    |-bower.json                                                        # standard format
    |-karma.conf.js                                                     # *** HELP!
    |-test-main.js                                                      # *** Save Our Souls!!!
```

---

***karma.conf.js***

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Wed Nov 19 2014 15:16:56 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      //'test/spec/test-test-file.js',
      //'lib/**/*.js',
      //'src/**/*.js',
      //'test/spec/**/*.js',
      'test-main.js',
      {pattern: 'lib/**/*.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'src/**/*.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'test/spec/*.js', included: true}
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
        'lib/**/!(angular|angular-mocks|angular-resource|angular-route|require|text).js',
        'lib/**/**/!(jquery|bootstrap).js',
        'src/app.js'
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

***test-main.js***

```
var allTestFiles = [];
var TEST_REGEXP = /(spec|test)\.js$/i;

var pathToModule = function(path) {
    return path.replace(/^\/base\//, '').replace(/\.js$/, '');
};

Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function(file) {
    if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
        // Normalize paths to RequireJS module names.
        allTestFiles.push(pathToModule(file));
    }
});

require.config({
    // Karma serves files under /base, which is the basePath from your config file
    baseUrl: '/base/src',
    
    paths: {
        
        angular: '../lib/angular/angular',
        ngRoute: '../lib/angular-route/angular-route',
        jquery: '../lib/jQuery/dist/jquery',
        bootstrap: '../lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap',
        models: 'models',
        controllers: 'controllers',
        globals: 'globals',
        routeMap: 'routeMap'
    },
    shim: {
        angular: {
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        ngRoute: {
            deps: ['angular']
        },
        jquery: {
            exports: '$'
        },
        bootstrap: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    },

    // dynamically load all test files
    deps: allTestFiles,

    // we have to kickoff jasmine, as it is asynchronous
    callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

***test-test-file.js***

```
console.log('....................');

define(function(){
    //console.log('testing test-file', testFile);
    
    describe('Testing testing', function(){
        it('should work', function(){
            expect(true).toEqual(true);
        });
    });

});
```

***test-file.js***

```
define('testFile', [], function(){
    
    return function init(sandbox){
        var app, application = app = sandbox.app
          , globals = sandbox.globals;
        
        return {
            some: 'module'
        };
    };
    
});
```

---

**Questions & Descriptions**

Key points I would love to hear answers for are

- what does { pattern: '...', **include: true|false** } do?
- best way to exclude all the extra stuff inside the bower directories.
- what files do I need to include in the test-main.js file?
- what files do I need to include in the karma.conf.js file?
- what does test-main.js actually do; what's it for?

The times I receive errors & issues is as soon as I wrap my spec in a `define(...)` call -- event when I give the module an ID -- `define('someId', function(){ ... })` -- *do I need to return something out of this module, as it is a `define` call?*

Other times, I receive the 'ol *ERROR: 'There is no timestamp for /base/src/app.js!'*. "Timestamp, of course! How silly of me..." -- what in the world does this mean?! Sometimes I get the infamous "*Executed 0 of 0 ERROR*" -- I could also use some clarity here, please. Really, I get plenty of *ERROR: '...no timestamp...'* errors -- and even `404`s when it *seems* I should be pulling that library in with the karma.conf.js `files` config...???

It even seems that usually when I explicitly tell karma to exclude`src/app.js` I still get `404`s and errors.

**tl;dr**

Obviously, I'm a bit of a confused novice about Karma and *DD at large...

I can run `test-test-file.js` fine when my karma.conf.js `files` array looks like `[ 'test-main.js', 'test/spec/test-test-file.js' ]` -- but, still, if I wrap my test in a RequireJS define call I get the "*Mismatching anonymous define()*" error mentioned above.

It seems that when I add *{ pattern: '...', include: **false** }* then karma just doesn't add any of my files for the given pattern whatsoever (???).

If someone can even simply direct me toward how to use RequireJS with Karma -- namely so that I can just wrap my tests in a *define/require* call and pull in the module I want to test... That would be greatly appreciated.

As its somewhat difficult to keep these types of questions short and still provide adequate information, I hope I didn't make it too long.

---

#### EDIT

After reading the answer from glepretre and some fiddling on my own, I reconfigured my project as follows:

- Moved `test-main.js` to `test/test-main.js`,
- renamed *test-test-file.js* to *testFileSpec.js* -- moved it from `test/spec` to `test/`,

***karma.conf.js:***

```
...
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
    {pattern: 'lib/**/*.js', included: false},
    {pattern: 'src/**/*.js', included: false},
    {pattern: 'test/**/*Spec.js', included: false},
    
    'test/test-main.js'
  
],
....
```

**test/test-main.js:**

```
/* **************** HOW COME THE DEFAULT (Karma-generated) CONFIGURATION DOES ***NOT WORK???
var allTestFiles = [];
var TEST_REGEXP = /(spec|test)\.js$/i;

var pathToModule = function(path) {
    return path.replace(/^\/base\//, '').replace(/\.js$/, '');
};

Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function(file) {
    if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
        // Normalize paths to RequireJS module names.
        allTestFiles.push(pathToModule(file));
    }
});
*/

var tests = [];
for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
    if (/Spec\.js$/.test(file)) {
        tests.push(file);
    }
}

require.config({
    // Karma serves files under /base, which is the basePath from your config file
    baseUrl: '/base/src',
    
    paths: {},
    shim: {},

    // dynamically load all test files
    //deps: allTestFiles,
    //
    deps: tests,

    // we have to kickoff jasmine, as it is asynchronous
    callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

**I am now running Unit Tests successfully! *Special Thanks to glepretre & all other contributors*.**

---

Thanks for any insight at all :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

OK, I will try to address each question at a time:

**Question 1**

> - what does { pattern: '...', **included: true|false** } do?

Karma's default behavior is to:

- find all files matching the **`pattern`** (mandatory property)
- watch them for changes (**`watched`** option) in order to restart your unit tests to give you live result when you are editing your code (works if only you leave the default `autoWatch` default value to `true`).
- serve them using its own webserver (**`served`** option)
- include them in the browser using `<script>` (**`included`** option)

So, in the `files` array of the karma config you can use default behavior by adding only string patterns:

```js
files: [
  // this will match all your JS files 
  // in the src/ directory and subdirectories
  'src/**/*.js'
]
```

Or use the full object syntax to customize each option:

```js
files: [
  {pattern: 'src/**/*.js', watched: true, served: true, included: false}
]
```

Using requireJS, you DO NOT want them to be included because it will be in conflict with requireJS behavior!

> **Included. Description:** Should the files be included in the browser using `<script>` tag? Use false if you want to load them manually, eg. using *Require.js*.

from [karma/config/files docs](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/files.html)

*NB: Pay attention to the order in which you add the files/patterns in the array. It matters! For more understanding, set `logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG` in your karma config.*

**Question 2**

> - what files do I need to include in the karma.conf.js file?

At least all required files for the proper functioning of your components for unit testing.

Basically, all files listed in your `define([])` and `require()` blocks.

**Question 3**

> - best way to exclude all the extra stuff inside the bower directories.

What are you trying to do exactly?

Based on what I wrote before, you can see that you can add selectively the files you will need in your tests.

I use to add the pattern `'/bower_components/**/*.js'` and even `'/bower_components/**/*.html'` when my bower packages are using templates. I never noticed any significant performance issue if that's what you are worried about... Up to you to define the file patterns you will need.

**Question 4 & 5**

> - what does test-main.js actually do; what's it for?
> - what files do I need to include in the test-main.js file?

The purpose of the `test-main.js` file is to find and load your test files before starting Karma. It connects the dots between Karma and requireJS

You must choose a convention to name your test files and then define the `TEST_REGEXP` to match all of them.

The "official" [angular style guide and best practices for app structure](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub) recommends using the suffix `*_test.js`.

*EDIT:* Your regexp is not working because it is defined to catch `"spec.js" || "test.js"` at the end or your spec file name is ending by `"file.js"` ;) Please see http://regex101.com/r/bE9tV9/1

**One more thing**

I hope I was clear enough. You can have a look at our starter app structure for our projects using Angular + Require: [angular-requirejs-ready](https://github.com/glepretre/angular-requirejs-ready). It's already set up and tested with both Karma and Protractor.

Comment: glepretre, thank you tons for your thorough and very helpful answer -- this helped me out lots. The only thing -- and I will mark your answer as 'Accepted' -- now that I am running tests successfully, I would like to know more about the config settings in `test-main.js`. I switched from the Karma-generated "allTestFiles" & `var TEST_REGEXP = /(spec|test)\.js$/i;` to that which is available online, `var tests = [];` & `if (/Spec\.js$/.test(file)) {...}` (please see my edit above). Could you elaborate on this for us 'non-RegExp' coders? Just want to understand WHY this was failing for me--Thanks

Comment: @Cody Sure, your old regexp was defined to catch `"spec.js" || "test.js"` at the end or your spec file name was ending by `"file.js"` ;) Please see http://regex101.com/r/bE9tV9/1. You're welcome, I'm glad if that helped you!

Comment: you absolutely helped me! Thanks a ton (tons). Awesome answer(s) -- I will mark this as the Accepted Answer -- Cheers