# Grunt Karma Backbone not defined

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, mocha.js, karma-runner

I believe this is similar to the following issue, but I cannot locate where the configuration breakdown had occurred. https://github.com/karma-runner/grunt-karma/issues/52

**command prompt error**

```
Connected on socket (censored) with id (censored)
Chrome 45.0.2454 (Windows 8.1.x) ERROR
 Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone not defined at c:/path/base/dir/backbone-validation/dist/backbone-validation-min.js:8
```

**standard backbone-validation.js install**

```
Backbone.Validation = (function(_) { ... })
```

Below is the configuration definitions with relative paths.

**package.json**

```
dependencies:{},
devDependencies: {
  grunt: '^0.4.5',
  grunt-karma: '^0.12.1',
  karma-requirejs: '0.2.2'
  requirejs: '^2.1.20'
  ...

}
```

**test config file**

```
require.config({ 
    baseUrl: 'path',
    paths: {
     'jquery': '../dir/jquery/dist/jquery',
     'backbone': '../dir/backbone/backbone',
     'underscore': '../dir/underscore/underscore',
     'backbone.validation': '../dir/backbone/backbone-validation/dist/backbone-validation'
    },
    shim: {
      'backbone': {
        deps: ['underscore','jquery'],
        exports: 'Backbone'   
      },

      'backbone.validation': {
         deps: ['backbone'],
         exports: 'Backbone'
       }
    }

    ...

})
```

**karma config file**

```
module.exports = function(c) {
 c.set({
  basePath: 'base',
  frameworks: ['requirejs', 'jasmine'],
  files: [
   {pattern: 'karma.conf.js'},
   {pattern: 'path/dir/jquery/dist/*.js', included: true, served: true}, 
   {pattern: 'path/dir/underscore/**/*.js', included: true, served: true}, 
   {pattern: 'path/dir/backbone/*.js', included: true, served: true}, 
   {pattern: 'path/dir/**/*.js', included: true, served: true}, 
   {pattern: 'path/js-scripts/**/*.js', included: true, served: true}, 
   {pattern: 'test-files/**/*.js'}
  ]
  ...

 })
}
```

When opening the developer console in the browser, I can see the underscore, jquery, and backbone-validation files (among a few others not specified here) as included in the "sources" tab, but the "backbone" definition is missing. Can anyone point me in the direction of where my configuration might be incorrect?

// EDIT 9/23
I've also tried permutations of "backbone-validation" and "backboneValidation".

// EDIT Sept.23.11:54

**karma.conf.js** updated to have included/served values based on the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050180/karmajs-jasmine-requirejs-etc-how-to-use-require-for-testing-modules?rq=1 but now I receive the error requirejs mismatched define. define(['pkg','dep'], function(a,b) {...}) That looks like the correct syntax to me.

```
// 
files: [
    {'pattern': '../test/spec/unit/**/*.js'},
    {'pattern': 'assets/js/jquery/dist/jquery/*.js', served: true},
    {'pattern': 'assets/js/backbone/backbone.js', served: true},
    {'pattern': 'assets/js/**/*.js', served: true, included: true},
    {'pattern': 'assets/scripts**/*.js', served: true, included: false}
]
```

Comment: I fixed the code formatting for you. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks for how to do that.

Comment: I'm not using backbone, but i think your shim for backbone-validation is wrong (should be "Backbone.Validation"). Also, jquery doesnt need a shim

Comment: Also there's a single quote missing from underscore in `requirejs.config`, not sure if it's relevant to the problem or just copy paste error)

Comment: underscore is amd compliant, so no shim needed

Comment: Thanks @PeteTNT for the format update. Re: syntax, thanks for the suggestion. I have validated the actual file does not suffer from this issue. Re: backbone.validation vs BackboneValidation vs backboneValidation vs BackboneValidation all formats result in the same error as defined above.

Comment: @JoshuaGentes Backbone 1.2.3 does not need a `shim`.

Comment: @Louis Thank you for your suggestion. I updated the configurations of the spec file under test and reran and receive the same error. I then tried to adjust the require config file and there was no change there either.

Comment: Thoughts? I am still stumped here.